# Why snow pipe is not loading all the data

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am having data load issue from azure blob to snowflake.. I have created complete process(storage, notification integration, file format, stage, pipe). so when truncated table and created pipe, its only loading last 7 days file whereas in azure blob 1 years of file exist.

Can you please suggest how to dig into this issue?
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

By default ALTER PIPE REFRESH command loads staged files only from the last 7 days.
If the files are older than 7 days, you can use the direct COPY INTO command to load all the files one time. Use the keyword PATTERN to specify the regular expressions for the file names to be loaded.

Please have a look at the [Snowflake documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-manage.html#loading-historic-data) for more details

Note: The REFRESH functionality is intended for short-term use to resolve specific issues when Snowpipe fails to load a subset of files and is not intended for regular use.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the REFRESH command as documented [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-auto-azure.html#step-5-load-historical-files)

Comment: yes. after trying this it loaded last 7 days files.. Prior to those files are still yet to load.. if Pipe is correct and allowing to load last 7 days file then it should load rest of all files which exist is azure blob.. not sure why rest files are not loading

Answer (score 0):

You need to open a support case, to debug this further. There can be certain issue with the notification channel, and this needs to be debugged.